# Javascript Unresponsive Script Error

Tags: javascript, api, highcharts

I am trying to get data to load on my chart from an API.  All the data is getting to the chart correctly, but the chart doesn't load and I get the unresponsive script error.  I'm using Highcharts.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.  My code is below.

**Model**

```
public function ajax_get_chart() {

    $quotes = $this->rest->get('api/1/BTCUSD/trades/fetch');
    $series_data = array();
    $results = $quotes->return;
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($results as $quote)
    {
        $series_tmp = array(
            'date'      =>  $quote->date,
            'price'     =>  $quote->price
        );
        $series_data[]= $series_tmp;
        $i= $i+1;
    }
    die (json_encode($series_data));
    return TRUE;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chart;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/chart/ajax_get_chart", // the URL of the controller action method
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) 
        {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Price'
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Date'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    reversed: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return ''+
                            this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {},
                series: result
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `die()` for a normal exit?

Comment: I got rid of the die() and I no longer get the error and now the chart shows up in the container but its just the white background of the chart, no data.

Comment: Did you replace it with `echo`? Or maybe `return`, depending on how the function is being called?

Comment: How much data there is? Generally "unresponsive script" is caused because the JS code is taking too long to execute. This would lead me to believe the amount of data is so big it takes forever to render the chart.

Comment: There is A LOT of data, its bitcoin prices updating live every second

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is that there's too much data to present.

You can try using a speedier browser (Chrome usually works pretty fast), limiting the data, or trying another charting library.

Limiting the data is probably the most likely one to work. If you need to show all the data, the best way to go about it would be to only load partial data and then if the user for example scrolls the chart, load the missing data.

Another way to present more data at the same time would be to calculate averages for the data on server. For example, if the ticker data is from every second, you could pre-calculate hourly or even daily averages on the server. This generally allows you to show a relatively accurate chart without causing performance problems, and many libraries also support dynamically loading more accurate data if you zoom the chart.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I would want to go with loading partial data then more loads when the user scrolls the chart.  However, I'm not exactly sure on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts can not handle so huge number of data, but using Highstock with dataGrouping or lazy-loading you should be able to handle a lot of points, see [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading).

Also [this article](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/48-loading-millions-of-points-in-highcharts) should help.